# Is there a method to fill spaces outside interpolation region?

Tags: python, numpy, methods, scipy, interpolation

I need to create an interpolation for irregularly spaced data that covers an specific area in Python. However, there aren't enough data in the borders to complete interpolation.

- I have trying differents interpolations methods of griddata (linear, nearest and cubic) and some methods of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html but although change interpolate pattern, it don't extend interpolation to the borders. *See image in:* [Image of interpolation using each method: Cubic and Nearest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bloV.png)
- Also, I have adding a "fill_value" that covers all region area than not have a value, but it can only allows a scalar and singular input value. *See image in:* [Image of interpolation using fill_value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7omH.png)

Of course, I also could ask for data from states around this area but I would like to avoid this as long as I don't get an alternative solution.

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# grid data
numcols, numrows = 6000, 6000
xi = np.linspace(min(list1), max(list1), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(min(list2), max(list2), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# interpolate
x, y, z = data['projected_lon'].values, data['projected_lat'].values, data.Valor.values
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='cubic',fill_value = 320)

con = m.contourf(xi, yi, zi, zorder=3, alpha=0.6, cmap='Blues')
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "extrapolation" if you want to go outside the borders ;)

Comment: You might be able to use np.pad with the linear_ramp option to extrapolate outside a given data range